# Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content every time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Twitter bootstrap, I have specified a modal

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modal-item">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Update Item</h3>
    </div>

    <form action="http://www.website.example/update" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="modal-body">
        Loading content...
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update Item</button>
    </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

And the links

```
<a href="http://www.website.example/item/1" data-target="#modal-item" data-toggle="modal">Edit 1</a>
<a href="http://www.website.example/item/2" data-target="#modal-item" data-toggle="modal">Edit 2</a>
<a href="http://www.website.example/item/3" data-target="#modal-item" data-toggle="modal">Edit 2</a>
```

When I click on any of these link for the first time, I see the correct content, but when I click on other links it shows the same content loaded for the first time, it doesn't update the content.

I want it to be updated every time its clicked.

P.S: I can easily make it work via custom jQuery function, but I want to know if it's possible with native Bootstrap modal remote function, as it should be easy enough and I guess I am just complicating things.

Comment: Same Fix, but modified for Bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 3 introduces namespaces. http://plnkr.co/edit/HWSgSw?p=preview

Comment: Note that [`remote` Modals are deprecated as of Bootstrap v3.2.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034) and will be gone in v4.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The problem is two-fold.

**First**, once a Modal object is instantiated, it is persistently attached to the element specified by `data-target` and subsequent calls to show that modal will only call `toggle()` on it, but will not update the values in the `options`. So, even though the `href` attributes are different on your different links, when the modal is toggled, the value for `remote` is not getting updated. For most options, one can get around this by directly editing the object. For instance:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.remote = "http://website.example/item/7";
```

#### However, that won't work in this case, because...

**Second**, the Modal plugin is designed to load the remote resource *in the constructor* of the Modal object, which unfortunately means that even if a change is made to the `options.remote`, *it will never be reloaded*.

A simple remedy is to destroy the Modal object before subsequent toggles. One option is to just destroy it after it finishes hiding:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

<sub>**Note:** Adjust the selectors as needed. This is the most general.</sub>

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMofRZ?p=preview)

Or you could try coming up with a more complicated scheme to do something like check whether the link launching the modal is different from the previous one. If it is, destroy; if it isn't, then no need to reload.

Comment: Thanks, Though i understand this., I think this is the best solution (atleast for now)

Hopefully they will fix this in later versions of Bootstrap.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Sorry about that - seems I forgot the `hide` class on the modal, so if your window was too small, the modal may have been blocking mouse events on the buttons.  For some reason JSFiddle.net is really bad this morning (got a 504 trying to update), so I just redid the example on plnkr.co, which is better for AJAX anyway.

Comment: This wasn't working for me on IE, so I decided to go with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059187/271985

Comment: @dadwithkids - I know plnkr.co doesn't work with IE, but that should only be an issue with my example, not the actual workaround.  Did you try the workaround in your code?

Comment: there's one other issue: the .modal-body will still have the text in it, so I added: <CODE>      $('#myModal .modal-body').text("Loading...")</CODE> in the hidden event listener

Comment: `bs.modal` in `$(this).removeData('bs.modal')` worked for me with Bootstrap 3

Comment: Full working code for Boostrap 3 is `$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(this).removeData('bs.modal'); });`

Comment: This work for me. I was filling the model data after ajax call by replacedata method. This was causing the error. Now, I replace replaceData method with html method and use this code $(this).removeData('modal');

Comment: Adding .html('') to the end of the chain helps, as the HTML doesn't actually clear from the old modal until it's replaced by the new data.  Clearing it when you remove the modal object makes for a much cleaner action.

Comment: @merv : very useful answer but when i used http://myip:1111 in <a href> then it will throw error..  not working. any other idea ??

Comment: I would also check if modal being hidden is loaded from remote source, so as not to break modals with static content:

`var modalData = $(this).data('bs.modal'); if (modalData && modalData.options.remote)...`

Comment: if you have multiple modals then you can also use it like `$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '{particular model id/class}', function () { $(this).removeData('bs.modal'); }); `
**{particular model id/class}** replace these by your modal id/class

**This  will only work for {particular model id/class}.**

Comment: @merv I've read your explanation. I'm facing what I believe is a similar problem. I'd thank you if you could take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682773/jquery-result-of-script-gets-deleted-after-execution-removedata-running-on  thanks beforehand

Answer (score 171):

For bootstrap 3 you should use:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Bootstrap 3 isn't backward compatible and most of the content on SO (or other forums) is about BS < 3, trying those solutions wastes a lot of time indeed.

Comment: No perfect: it briefly shows the old content before the new content.

Comment: I ended up using this inside the callback instead: $(this).find("input[type='text'], input[type='email'], textarea").val("");

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so that the old content is not shown briefly?

Comment: If you want to empty the modal using the above example you should be able to add the following either before or after the `remoteData` line: `$(this).empty()`

Comment: You shouldn't use `$(this).empty()`. The `remote` option loads the remote data into the nested `<div class="modal-content">` element. Use `$('.modal-content', this).empty();` instead.

Answer (score 50):

For Bootstrap 3.1 you'll want to remove data and empty the `modal-content` rather than the whole dialog (3.0) to avoid the flicker while waiting for remote content to load.

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

If you are using non-remote modals then the above code will, of course, remove their content once closed (bad). You may need to add something to those modals (like a `.local-modal` class) so they aren't affected. Then modify the above code to:

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal:not(.local-modal)", function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

Comment: On the remote pages make sure you're not loading bootstrap, or jquery libraries. It will kill any reference and leave you with empty an empty modal.

Comment: This wasn't working for me. Here is my code which is working :

    $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal", function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is(".local-modal")) {
            $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty(); 
        }
    });

Comment: When I use `$(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();` it's like my modal somehow gets hidden and only the gray overlay appears.

Answer (score 30):

Thanks merv. I started tinkering around boostrap.js but your answer is a quick and clean workaround. Here's what I ended up using in my code.

```
$('#modal-item').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, so I went with JavaScript to do it.

```
<a href="/foo" class="modal-link">
<a href="/bar" class="modal-link">

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".modal-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#myModal').removeData("modal")
        $('#myModal').modal({remote: $(this).attr("href")})
    })
})
```

Answer (score 14):

This works with Bootstrap 3 FYI

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

My project is built in Yii & uses the Bootstrap-Yii plugin, so this answer is only relevant if you're using Yii.

The above fix did work but only after the first time the modal was shown. The first time it came up empty. I think that's because after my initiation of the code Yii calls the hide function of the modal thereby clearing out my initiation variables.

I found that putting the removeData call immediately before the code that launched the modal did the trick. So my code is structured like this...

```
$ ("#myModal").removeData ('modal');
$ ('#myModal').modal ({remote : 'path_to_remote'});
```

Answer (score 5):

In Bootstrap 3.2.0 the "on" event has to be on the document and you have to empty the modal :

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

In Bootstrap 3.1.0 the "on" event can be on the body :

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: The 3.2 solution was the only thing that worked properly for me in Bootstrap 3.1 - using the body approach, some of my events on modal became unhooked.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it more general with BS 3? Just use "[something]modal" as the ID of the modal DIV.

```
$("div[id$='modal']").on('hidden.bs.modal',
    function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Only working option for me is:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalBox', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I use Bootstrap 3 and I have a function called
`popup('popup content')`
which appends the modal box html.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me with BS 3.3.6. also using handlebars template. I suggest using document instead of body however.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an $(this).html(''); to clear visible data as well, and it works pretty fine

Answer (score 1):

If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's **load** method and injected into the .modal-content div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added something like this, because the older content is shown until the new one appears, with .html('') inside the .modal-content will clear the HTML inside, hope it helps

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
   $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').html('');
});
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest working answer I have found. Nothing complicated about the answer, few lines of code and easy to interpret. Worked perfectly first time withing messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple snippet handling the refreshing of the modal.
Basically it stores the clicked link in the modal's data and check if it's the same link that has been clicked, removing or not the modal data.

```
var handleModal = function()
{
    $('.triggeringLink').click(function(event) {
        var $logsModal = $('#logsModal');
        var $triggeringLink = $logsModal.data('triggeringLink');

        event.preventDefault();

        if ($logsModal.data('modal') != undefined
            && $triggeringLink != undefined
            && !$triggeringLink.is($(this))
        ) {
            $logsModal.removeData('modal');
        }

        $logsModal.data('triggeringLink', $(this));

        $logsModal.modal({ remote: $(this).attr('href') });
        $logsModal.modal('show');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 3, in modal.js I changed:

```
$(document)
  .on('show.bs.modal',  '.modal', function () { $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') })
  .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open'); })
```

to

```
$(document)
  .on('show.bs.modal',  '.modal', function () { $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') })
  .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal').empty()
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open')
  })
```

(extra spacing added for clarity)

This prevents any unwanted flash of old modal content by calling empty() on the modal container as well as removing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('modal');
        });
```

This one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This other approach works well for me:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
       $("#mention Id here what you showed inside modal body").empty()
});
```

Which html element you want to empty like(div,span whatever).

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="searchKaryawan" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SearchKaryawanLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="SearchKaryawanLabel">Cari Karyawan</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="location">
    <input name="cariNama" type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 3) cariNikNama();" />
    <div class="links-area" id="links-area"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div> </div></div>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {  $(".links-area").empty() }); </script>
```

links-area is area where i put the data and need to clear

Answer (score 0):

Expanded version of accepted answer by @merv. It also checks if modal being hidden is loaded from remote source and clears old content to prevent it from flashing.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  var modalData = $(this).data('bs.modal');

  // Destroy modal if has remote source – don't want to destroy modals with static content.
  if (modalData && modalData.options.remote) {
    // Destroy component. Next time new component is created and loads fresh content
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    // Also clear loaded content, otherwise it would flash before new one is loaded.
    $(this).find(".modal-content").empty();
  }
});
```

https://gist.github.com/WojtekKruszewski/ae86d7fb59879715ae1e6dd623f743c5

Answer (score -1):

Tested on Bootstrap version 3.3.2

```
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData();
  });
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Calling `.removeData()` with no parameters will tell jquery to remove all data attached to that element. As far the OP's problem is concerned, `.removeData('bs.modal')` or `.removeData('modal')` would suffice and is very safe.

Answer (score -4):

Good luck with this one:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: this is useless. reloading the page is not the solution.