# Load dynamic URL via modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have the following link that's generated X times by a loop.

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_more" href="/item/view/<?php echo $item_id; ?>">Launch Modal</a>
```

Here's the JS script that initiates the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#view_more').modal({
        remote: '/item/view/1',
        show:false
}); // Start the modal
```

It works when the `remote` url is hardcoded, but I would like it to be dynamic depending on what gets passed to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Modal plugin executes the `load()` method in its constructor, so the only way to change the remote content of a Modal (other than manually doing the AJAX yourself) is to destroy it before doing another call:

```
$('#view_more')
  .removeData('modal')
  .modal({
    remote: someURL,
    show: false
  });
```

There are more details in answer to a similar post: [Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287169/570918).

Comment: ok but how do i pass the correct URL into the `remote` field? If I have multiple links, they each call their own respective URL.

Comment: If you are including the remote url's in the `href` attributes of the anchors, the modal plugin will automatically use them as the `remote` value on initialization. The problem is that you need to destroy the modal object each time to get it to reinitialize on subsequent clicks. The option I suggested in the other answer I linked to is to destroy the modal object when a **hidden** event is fired.

Comment: I got it, I didnt realize the `href` gets passed automatically. Your solution works perfectly, thanks!