# Reload content in modal (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap's modal popup.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can load content using ajax with this a-element:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit.aspx">Open modal</a>
```

Now I have to open the same modal but using a different url. I'm using this modal to edit an entity from my database. So when I click edit on an entity I need to load the modal with an ID.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit.aspx?id=1">Open modal</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit.aspx?id=2">Open modal</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit.aspx?id=3">Open modal</a>
```

If I click on link number 1, it works fine. But if I then click on link number 2 the modal content is already loaded and therefor it will show the content from link number 1.

How can I refresh or reset the ajax loaded content in a twitter bootstrap modal popup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime)

Comment: Had the same issue and used to same solution. I resort to .attr() function from jquery for some strange reason .data() function was not working.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I guess the way of doing this will be to remove the data-toggle attribute and have a custom handler for the links.

Something in the lines of:

```
$("a[data-target=#myModal]").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    
    // load the url and show modal on success
    $("#myModal .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
         $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: $('.modal').on('hidden', function() { $(this).removeData(); }) this is my modification of below solution... cleaner because you dont have to catch the click and load it your self so programmatic model show still works

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3, the content in the modal does get refreshed each time but it creates two modal windows. Does anyone else get this?

Comment: Hey Sid, your creating 2 divs with the class "modal-body", actually you're already creating it, and the modal is creating again. From that code, remove the '.modal-body' and should work fine.

Comment: Works for me w/ Bootstrap 3, very frustrating that this is not supported by the core bootstrap library by default.

Comment: @markz, I am also using something like this and ev.preventDefault(); as well but still on click of link, when I get modal window, all my page's dropdown are getting reset. Any idea, how to prevent that?

Comment: this is what i need... Thanks

Answer (score 73):

To unload the data when the modal is closed you can use this with Bootstrap 2.x:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

And in Bootstrap 3 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/7935#issuecomment-18513516):

```
$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal')
});

//Edit SL: more universal
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: perfect. worked without any problem. in bootstrap 3. I used 

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
 $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});

Comment: No perfect: it briefly shows the old content before the new content.

Comment: @Laurent, you can clear out the previous contents by adding .html(''). So, for 2.x: $(this).removeData('modal').find('.modal-body').html(''). For 3: $(this).removeData('bs.modal').html('') 2.x loads content into the .modal-body, whereas 3 loads content straight into the .modal container

Comment: small correction on last comment, in bootstrap v3 should be:  $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal').html(''); This is the most elegant solution so far (but it delays a little bit).

Comment: I used the edit/version that @Softlion posted in this proposed solution - it worked and I didn't experience any speed/delay issues.

Answer (score 21):

You can force Modal to refresh the popup by adding this line at the end of the hide method of the Modal plugin (If you are using bootstrap-transition.js v2.1.1, it should be at line 836)

```
this.$element.removeData()
```

Or with an event listener

```
$('#modal').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).data('modal').$element.removeData();
})
```

Comment: -1 The idea of putting that first snippet into the Modal plugin directly is a terrible idea. If you were going to hack on the plugin (which I would avoid), the more reasonable thing to do would be to either move the `load()` call out of the constructor and into the `show()`, or add a method to the plugin to manually trigger a reload of `remote`. On the second suggestion, I only provided that as [an answer for a question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12287169/570918) which explicitly asked not to do it [the way @markz suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12513100/570918).

Comment: I like the listener approach. I think it can even be improved using '.modal' instead of '#modal' in order to avoid hardcoding the id. 
In my opinion it's a cleaner approach than markz's, because you keep using the data-toggle as in original bootstrap modal.

Comment: I wonder why this answer hasn't got much upvotes. This answer seems to be the first one suggesting an event listener which is quite interesting and quick to implement.

Answer (score 15):

With Bootstrap 3 you can use 'hidden.bs.modal' event handler to delete any modal-related data, forcing the popup to reload next time:

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: Yes, but there is still a crucial lag in this solution; it still shows old content for a second or three before the new.

Comment: instead of #modal try body

Answer (score 8):

Based on other answers (thanks everyone).

I needed to adjust the code to work, as simply calling .html wiped the whole content out and the modal would not load with any content after i did it.  So i simply looked for the content area of the modal and applied the resetting of the HTML there.

```
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        target.removeData('bs.modal')
              .find(".modal-content").html('');
    });
```

Still may go with the accepted answer as i am getting some ugly jump just before the modal loads as the control is with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

A little more compressed than the above accepted example. Grabs the target from the data-target of the current clicked anything with data-toggle=modal on. This makes it so you don't have to know what the id of the target modal is, just reuse the same one! less code = win! You could also modify this to load title, labels and buttons for your modal should you want to.

```
 $("[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // load the url and show modal on success
    $( $(this).attr('data-target') + " .modal-body").load($(this).attr("href"), function() { 
         $($(this).attr('data-target')).modal("show"); 
    });
});
```

Example Links:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/page/api?package=herp" data-target="#modal">click me</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/page/api?package=derp" data-target="#modal">click me2</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/page/api?package=merp" data-target="#modal">click me3</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a small change to [Softlion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449890/reload-content-in-modal-twitter-bootstrap#answer-18459248) answer, so all my modals won't refresh on hide.
The modals with data-refresh='true' attribute are only refreshed, others work as usual.
Here is the modified version.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('data-refresh') == 'true') {
        // Remove modal data
        $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
        // Empty the HTML of modal
        $(e.target).html('');
    }
});
```

Now use the attribute as shown below,

```
<div class="modal fade" data-refresh="true" id="#modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#modal-label" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

This will make sure only the modals with data-refresh='true' are refreshed. And i'm also resetting the modal html because the old values are shown until new ones get loaded, making html empty fixes that one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a coffeescript version that worked for me.

```
$(document).on 'hidden.bs.modal', (e) ->
  target = $(e.target)
  target.removeData('bs.modal').find(".modal-content").html('')
```

Comment: it resolved a problem where the content reload but js inside modal doesn't execute a second time

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on this problem then I saw that the *ids* of the modal are the same. You need different *ids* of modals if you want multiple modals. I used dynamic *id*. Here is my code in `haml`:

```
.modal.hide.fade{"id"=> discount.id,"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
```

you can do this

```
<div id="<%= some.id %>" class="modal hide fade in">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and your links to modal will be

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" href='"#"+<%= some.id %>' >Open modal</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href='"#"+<%= some.id %>' >Open modal</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href='"#"+<%= some.id %>' >Open modal</a>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It will works for all version of twitterbootstrap

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){
   var bsModal = null;
   $("[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var trgId = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
      if ( bsModal == null ) 
       bsModal = $(trgId).modal;
      $.fn.bsModal = bsModal;
      $(trgId + " .modal-body").load($(this).attr("href"));
      $(trgId).bsModal('show');
    });
 })();
/* <![CDATA[ */
</script>
```

links to modal are

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit1.aspx">Open modal 1</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit2.aspx">Open modal 2</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="edit3.aspx">Open modal 3</a>
```

pop up modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the AJAX loaded content removed when the modal closed, so I adjusted the line suggested by others (coffeescript syntax):

```
$('#my-modal').on 'hidden.bs.modal', (event) ->
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal').children().remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

var $table = $('#myTable2');
     $table.bootstrapTable('destroy');

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : Create a wrapper for the modal called `clone-modal-wrapper`.

step 2 : Create a blank div  called `modal-wrapper`.

Step 3 : Copy the modal element from `clone-modal-wrapper` to  `modal-wrapper`.

step 4 : Toggle the modal of `modal-wrapper`.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class='my-modal'>Open modal</a>

<div class="clone-modal-wrapper">
   <div class='my-modal' class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
               <h3>Header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-wrapper"></div>


$("a[data-target=#myModal]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal-wrapper").html($(".clone-modal-wrapper").html());
    $('.modal-wrapper').find('.my-modal').modal('toggle');
});
```