# Removing content cache from bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a dynamically generated list of links to show a modal window with ajax loaded content. Bootstrap automatically caches the content and doesn't clear it on modal hide event.

I need to get new content every time I click the link, how can I workaround this?
I checked and there are no methods or properties to set the caching to false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload content in modal (twitter bootstrap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449890/reload-content-in-modal-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
        <a href="/my/url" class="modal-toggle">test</a>


        $('body').on('click', '.modal-toggle', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.modal-content').empty();
            $('#myModal')
                .removeData('bs.modal')
                .modal({remote: $(this).attr('href') });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me..

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that has a similar problem, the solution that worked for me was:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to this, I've found out the above doesn't work with HTML5 video tags.

If you're dealing with HTML5 video, and the first video shown keeps displaying, even though you change the `<source>` tag. The removeData tip will not work in this case. So, to get around that issue, recreate the entire video element and it will work. I ran into this issue in Chrome 70.0.3538.110, so it may not be an issue in other browsers.

Example:

```
        var playerHtml = '<video id="someId" style="width: 100%;" controls>' +
            '<source src="' + someVideoUrl + '">' +
            '<p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>' +
            '</video>';

        $("#idOfDivWhereHtml5VideoElementShouldRender").html(playerHtml);
```

I hope that helps others having the HTML5 video issue :)