# Twitter Bootstrap: How to clear out a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page with links that trigger a modal called pop-up.  Here's the code for a typical link:

```
<a href="/user/profile?id=1" data-target="#pop-up" data-toggle="modal">Kevin Doherty</a>
```

'pop-up' is an empty DIV that is loaded as part of my layout.  Here it is:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="pop-up"></div>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to clear the content when the modal is closed.

The modal is populated using an ajax request.  I can tell that it's not clearing properly because:

- When I close the modal I can still see the HTML content using firebug, and
- If I click on a link that returns a 404, the modal still opens, but with the content from the previous request

I have read this question, 
[Reload content in modal (twitter bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449890/reload-content-in-modal-twitter-bootstrap), and I'm pretty sure I had this working earlier.  I can't get it working now though.  I'm wondering if a jQuery upgrade could be to blame?

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and jQuery 1.10.2.

Here's my code.  (I have tried several variations on this theme):

```
$(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#pop-up', function() {
    $('#pop-up').removeData('bs.modal');
    console.log('Modal reset!');
});
```

The code seems to execute when expected (as evidenced by the output in the console), but it doesn't clear the data.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a `bootply`? http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: You could always hit it with a hacksaw.. $('#pop-up.modal-title,#pop-up.modal-body,#pop-up.modal-footer').html(''); for example

Comment: This solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options.  1) clear the data after you close the modal, or 2) clear the data before you open the modal.

So, when you close the window, you clear the html

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).on 'click', '.close', ->
    $(this).parent().fadeOut -> $(this).html('')
```