# Modal View Reload Content (Bootstrap MVC ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Aloha, I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.6 within ASP.NET MVC4 Application to display pop-ups using modal-views.

Example for my modal:

```
<div class="modal-contents modal-view content-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body content-wrapper">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#approve-btn').click(function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

To load the modal I use Html.ActionLink like

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeText", "SomeAction", "SomeController", null , new { @class="modal-link"})
```

which triggers my script in my _Layout page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         // Initialize modal dialog
         // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
         // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
         $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
             $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
             console.log(this);
         });
         // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
         $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
             $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
         });
         //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded

         $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
             $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
         });

         $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
             return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

and finally the placeholder in my _Layout

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-view">
    </div>
</div>
```

This all is designed relying on this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826002/Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-Loading-Content-from-MVC-Pa and worked just fine. Until I tried to open a modal after I already have opened one in the same view. Then I would find the modal to contain the same data as before. 
After trying all suggestions from: 
[Reload content in modal (twitter bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449890/reload-content-in-modal-twitter-bootstrap) 
I got the feeling the problem is the refill of the #modal-container. 
The links are completed by the script in the right way, as I can say by debugging in chrome. 
If I reload the whole page the modal-view accepts new content. 
But since I use tabs (also relying on Bootstrap) reloading isn't an option because I would loose the current tab selection.

I'm very new to web-developing so it would be great if you've got some ideas.

Comment: What is the scenario where you are trying to open the modal with the same modal with different content already open?  That is a somewhat unusual scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime

Comment: It was badly described by me. I meant to close the modal and reopen it with another link (and data) from my parent view. 
I'm displaying a Webgrid and try to display different details. 
I already tried the most solutions of the question mentioned by you. 
But I will have a look for some of the spare ones.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

for clear the model state in your controller.

hope it will helps you.

Comment: No dude it's Model

Comment: His problem has nothing to do with ModelState.  His question is about the behavior of boostrap modals.