# Remove data from Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Referred this links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449890/reload-content-in-modal-twitter-bootstrap) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime) but not able clear the data's.

I am using bootstrap modal window in my web application. When modal is closed (triggered hidden event to clear the data), previously entered data's are not cleared.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk4gj48k/11/)` what i tried.Even I tried with form reset but not get success.

```
$("#modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#modal_form')[0].reset();
        $("#modal").removeData('bs.modal');
    });
    $("#modal").click(function() {

        $("#modal").removeData('bs.modal');
        $("#modal").modal();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `$("#myModal form")[0]` instead of `$("#myModal form")`

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { 
            $("#myModal form")[0].reset();
            $("#myModal form").find('span[style="color:red;"]').text(''); //reset error spans

          });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but the span text still shows. https://jsfiddle.net/bk4gj48k/13/

Answer (score 1):

If you give the form an ID, you can do the following in jQuery. You can also add a class to your error spans and reset all of them at the same time.

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#form").trigger('reset');
    $("#myModal .error").html('');
});


<span style="color:red;" id="username_span" class="error"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but the span text still shows. https://jsfiddle.net/bk4gj48k/13/

Comment: I updated my example. Let me know if there is anything else you are looking for.