# jquery append data-toggle modal atrribute to href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to open a modal with bootstrap 3 data-toggle="ajaxmodal". The link is appended to a div, the ajaxModal however is not working.

```
$('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>').html('Opponent: '+ opponentName + ',' + ' ' + 'Game amount: ' + message.amount + ' ' + 'tokens,' + ' ' + 'Game: ' + message.game + ' &nbsp; ' + '&nbsp; ' + '&nbsp; ' + '<a href="console/challengeView.php?id=' + message.gameID + '" id="viewButton"  class="btn btn-s-s btn-danger" onClick="return false;" data-toggle="ajaxModal">View</a>')).appendTo($('#pendingChallenges'));

$('#pendingChallenges')[0].scrollTop = $('#pendingChallenges')[0].scrollHeight;
```

I also tried

```
$("#viewButton").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('toggle')=='ajaxModal';
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `onClick="return false;"` ?

Comment: This one might be of help: [ajax content in bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971766/load-content-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-modal)