# want to display the jquery function result to the bootstrap model-body

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to display the jquery function result to the bootstrap model-body.

jquery function

```
 function randomNumberRange(min, max)
{
    var x= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    console.log(x);

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

in .html file model body is

```
<div class="modal-body">

          </div>
```

I want the value of x should get display in model body in html.

there is one submit button to launch model

```
<button onclick="location.href = '/poll/result/';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >submit</button>
</div>
```

so once i click on the submit it should display the value of x in model body.
Please help me out.

Comment: Look this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971766/load-content-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-modal

Comment: I am not using ajax for this.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">submit</button>
  <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function randomNumberRange(min, max)
{
    var x= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    console.log(x);

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal').modal({show:false});

  $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
    $('.modal-body').text(randomNumberRange(1,2));
    $('#modal').modal('show'); 
  });

})
```

[EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/126502)

Comment: hay thanks i got your answer but still i am not getting the result. Where do i need to put this code, inside the randomNumberRange() function or other place.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.modal-body').text(randomNumberRange(60, 100));
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
});
 });  its not working.

Comment: hay sorry for troubling you i am quite new to the jquery. I am sorry for troubling you.

Comment: I see, I changed my answer.