# Angular directive to decorate anchor tag with another directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to be a lil slick by having a directive decorate all my anchor tags in a given list with a directive so I do not have to copy/paste the same code over & over.

So far, it works great, except that when I launch the modal with the dynamically decorated links, I'm getting the raw image code vs the actual rendered image. In my testing, I was manually putting the directive on the top few links & letting it decorate the bootstrap modal attributes & it worked great.

This is the directive that decorates all the anchors in a list:

```
angular.module('wmApp.wmAddImageModal', [])

.directive('wmAddImageModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, $attrs) {
      var anchors = element.find('a');

      angular.forEach(anchors, function (anchor) {
        var a = angular.element(anchor);
        a.attr('data-wm-image-modal', '');
        a.attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        a.attr('data-target', '#wm-modal');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This is the directive when the anchors are clicked. I tried `data-ng-src` as well, with no luck:

```
angular.module('wmApp.wmImageModal', [])

.directive('wmImageModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
      element.on('click', function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        var imgUrl = window.location.origin + '/' + $attrs.href,
            content = '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">' + $attrs.title + '</h3></div>' +
                      '<div class="modal-body"><img src="' + imgUrl + '" width="100%"></div>';

        $('#wm-modal .modal-content').html(content); 
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And for the sake of completeness, I'm include the bootstrap modal scaffolding I'm using. The whole modal is not a child of the directive's element, but a sibling to the list:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="wm-modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The list of anchors as it is raw:

```
<ul data-wm-add-image-modal>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what it looks like after the `wm-add-image-modal` decorates each anchor:

```
<ul data-wm-add-image-modal>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description" data-wm-image-modal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wm-modal">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description" data-wm-image-modal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wm-modal">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>
      <a href="path/to/image.png" title="An awesome description" data-wm-image-modal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wm-modal">
        2016: Screenshot</a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      An awesome description
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The weird hieroglyph loading of the image. The modal itself is not the issue, it loads, just not the image:
[image: oddity]

**EDIT #1**: I'm seeing that only the 1st anchor is triggering the directive when debugging with a breakpoint in the directive. If I pull up the image once in another tab, then that SAME first image will load every time I click any link in the list, but on the same hand. I can tell it's recognizing the different anchor being clicked by the value of the `content` variable in the `wmImageModal` directive with a breakpoint/watch.

I can see the `modal-content` element update with the same data being displayed when clicking a decorated anchor, but it doesn't ever display the image. Any ideas?  Directly loading the images in a new tab show the images and NOT 'heiroglyphs'.

**EDIT #2:** For giggles, I added a console.log to the wmImageModal directive and simplified the `content` string:

`console.log('element', element, content);`

The results of that console.log:
[image]

The element itself is different for each link clicked & evidenced by the value of `content` output as well. I manually added the `data-wm-image-modal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#wm-modal"` attributes to the top 5 links in my list. The 1st click gives me the 'heiroglyph' image, then any subsequent clicks actually load the image.

Something is happening to the value of `content` when using jQuery's `$('#wm-modal .modal-content').html(content)` before it gets rendered.

**EDIT #3:**
Ok, I'm finding that there are 2 requests being made for the image, one being an XHR on the network tab of dev tools, but I'm not entirely sure why. It's definitely jQuery (v2.2.3) & Bootstrap (v3.3.6) doing this.

The img request, happening 1st with call stack:
[image]

The XHR request, happening 2nd with call stack:
[image]

The XHR request details, notice the `Accept` request header:
[image]

And here's the relevant lines from the XHR call stack:

```
send                    @  lib.js:9203      xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
jQuery.extend.ajax      @  lib.js:8684      try { state = 1; transport.send( requestHeaders, done ); }
jQuery.fn.load          @  lib.js:9450      jQuery.ajax( { url: url, type: type || "GET", dataType: "html", data: params } )
Modal                   @  lib.js:46913     this.$element.find('.modal-content').load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () { this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal') }, this))
(anonymous function)    @  lib.js:47179     if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
jQuery.extend.each      @  lib.js:365       for ( ; i < length; i++ ) { if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {break;} }
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each   @  lib.js:137       each: function( callback ) { return jQuery.each( this, callback ); },
Plugin                  @  lib.js:47174     function Plugin(option, _relatedTarget) { return this.each(function () { 
(anonymous function)    @  lib.js:47217     Plugin.call($target, option, this)
jQuery.event.dispatch   @  lib.js:4737      ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle || handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );
elemData.handle         @  lib.js:4549      return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ? jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
```

Comment: 1st can you replace `src`with `ng-src`, I think this might be better. Secondly I can't see where you attach `.modal-content`, but if it is attached to every image div, than every image div will replaced with `$('#wm-modal .modal-content').html(content);` Have you logged what you get for `content ` and tried to manually add it in chrome dev?

Comment: I've tried ng-src, but it's not a controller value being rendered for src, it's a concatenated string. The `$('#wm-modal .modal-content')` is being updated. It's not included in my code above because that part is working, but it's your typical bootstrap modal scaffolding and it's only ONE modal that's contents get updated on click. I have looked at what `content` renders as with a breakpoint/watcher, the value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is another attribute that I was not aware of for Bootstrap's modal: `data-remote`

Setting it to `false` makes the XHR request go away & an image to load.

```
data-remote="false"
```

I still have an issue though of adding the attributes dynamically will not display any content.

The clue that gave me the solution was found on this thread & when implemented, it immediately began working correctly: [Load content with ajax in bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971766/load-content-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-modal)