# Call Bootstrap Modal that loads another HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this table where, When a user clicks on a row, should open a modal with some information regarding that row.
Since the content of this Modal is on another HTML file within my project, I don't know how to accomplish it.

So far, I can do this for each row:

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" href="../clients/edit.html" data-id="10238" data-target=".clientEditModal">
  <td>10238</td>
  <td>eduardo@pingpong.com</td>
  <td>14.10.2013</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to do something like this via Javascript:

```
$(".table-clickable").find("tr").dblclick(function(){
  $('.clientEditModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

Is there a way to specify an HTML file to load as a model using Javascript `modal('show')`?

Comment: With the Bootstrap 3.3 update and deprecation, the linked answer is no longer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use remote urls has been deprecated in the most recent versions of bootstrap. Try something along the lines of

```
// Fill modal with content from link href
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

for full context please see marcovtwout's answer over at: [Load content with ajax in bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971766/load-content-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-modal)