# MODAL HELP - how to pull row data per user id w/ PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my code which I've revised so that it properly opens up my modal. I'm still facing issues passing table variables to the modal so that they can be edited according to which row you wish to edit with the click of the edit buttion.

```
   <html>
    <head>    
        <title>Admin View</title>    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>

        <!-- container with table headers / user records / edit function / approve function -->    
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                <center>
                    <thead> 
                        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </center>

                <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF">   
                    <?php         
                    $i = 1; foreach($users as $u)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <tr style="font-size: 20;">

                        <td width="5%;"> <?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($u->approved) ? "Approved" : "Pending"; ?></td>

                        <!--edit button-->
                        <td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td> 

                        <!--approve button-->
                        <td><a href= "/ci/index.php/myform/approve/?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok gi-15x" style='color: green'></span></a></td> 

                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; } ?>
                </tbody> 
                <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <center>
                <thead> 
                    <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Actions</th>        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </center>

            <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF">   
                <?php         
                $i = 1; foreach($users as $u) {
                ?>
                <tr style="font-size: 20;">

                    <td width="5%;"> <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($u->approved) ? "Approved" : "Pending"; ?></td>

                    <!--edit button-->
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal<?php echo $u->id;?>"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td> 

                    <!--approve button-->
                    <td><a href= "/ci/index.php/myform/approve/?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok gi-15x" style='color: green'></span></a></td> 


                </tr>

    <!--modal-->

<div class='modal fade' id='editModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='editModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'> 
        <div class='modal-dialog'> 
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id='modalHeading'>Entry for User ID <?php echo $u->$id; ?></h3>
                </div>
                <!--modal body-->
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <form action='' method='post'>

                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <label for='First Name'>First Name</label> 
                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='first_name' value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"><br/>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <label for='Last Name'>Last Name</label>
                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='last_name' value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>"/><br/>
                        </div> 

                        <div class='form-group'> 
                            <label for='Email'>Email</label>
                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-group'> 
                            <label for='Approved'>Approved</label>
                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo $approved; ?>"/><br/>
                        </div>              
                </div>

                <!--modal footer-->  
                <div class='modal-footer'> 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> 
                </div> 
                </form>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div> 

                <?php } ?>
            </tbody> 
        </table>


     <!--attempt at ajax function for approve success class    
    <script>

      $('.edit').on("click", function(){
        // user id stored when row edit clicked
        var userid = $(this).data('id');

        $ajax({

          url: $(this).attr('href'), 
          method: 'POST', 
          success: function (data) {

            $('#row_' + userid).addClass('success')
          },

          error: function (data) {

            $('#row_' + userid).addClass('danger')
          }
        });
      });


    </script>
    -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help!

Comment: Try print_r($users);  and see if it contains data.

Comment: You have to load your data using ajax, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971766/load-content-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-modal

Comment: how you declare the $users variable?

Comment: Can you add your controller code so we can see how you're passing the variables?

Comment: `public function edituser($user_id = NULL)
{
 $post = $this->input->post(); 
 if ($post){
  $id = $post['id']; 
  unset($post['id']); 
  $this->db->where("id", $id); 
  $this->db->update("User_Inputs", $post); 
  redirect("/myform/getdatabase");
 }
 else
 { 
  $user_id = (int) $user_id;
  $data['user'] = $this->db
   ->where('id', $user_id)
   ->get("User_Inputs")
   ->row();
  $this->load->view('editfields', $data['user']);

 }
}`

Comment: @Mr.Jibz - update your question and add controller code there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the modal inside your foreach and  make your `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal<?php echo $u->id;?>"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'>` and your `<div class='modal fade' id='editModal<?php echo $u->id;?>' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='editModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>` . I also have my whole code for that using MySQLi Object-oriented, I hope that this will help your problem.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username"; //username
$password = "password"; //password
$dbname = "myDB"; //myDB

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ACE | aice09</title>
    <!--Bootstrap 3.3.7 CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Data Tables-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
    <!--Date Timepicker-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default mynavbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav><!--/navbar navbar-default mynavbar-->

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location.href = '#'">Users</a></li>
      <li class="active"><b>Data</b></li>
    </ol><!--/breadcrumb-->

<!--////////////Start the Content Here//////////////////-->

<div class="container-fluid" style="">
    <!-- Data Table Here -->
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" style="width: 3%">NO</th>                
                <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">CLIENT ID</th>                
                <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 10%">NAME</th>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center">ADDRESS</th>
                <th rowspan="2" style="width: 5%"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 18%">BARANGAY </th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 18%;">MUNICIPALITY </th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 18%;">PROVINCE </th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 18%;">COUNTRY </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $id=1;
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id++;?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row['clientid'] ?></td>
                <td><a data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="<div class='media'><a href='#'' class='pull-left'><img src='<?php echo $row['image'] ?>' class='media-object' alt='<?php echo $row['name'] ?> Image'></a><div class='media-body'><h4 class='media-heading'><?php echo $row['name'] ?></h4><p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p></div></div>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['barangay'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['municipality'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['province'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['country'] ?></td>
                <th><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row['clientid'] ?>">EDIT</a> <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="lnr lnr-trash"></span> </a> </th>
            </tr>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $row['clientid'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ADD SOMETHING</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>This for <?php echo $row['name'] ?> modal</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <?php
                 }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div><!--/container-fluid-->

<!--////////////End of Content Here//////////////////-->

<!--Data Table JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
    .mynavbar{
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mymodalbutton{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //data-table
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: please see my revised code above. now it's only loading id 1 as a single row in my table. when i click that it's continuing to say undefined variables. is it the data target in my modal?

Comment: Please try my given code and see the difference, and give me feedback whatever you difference you identify.