# Output a PHP GD image as a popup(modal) after it has been sent to the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a project trying to write text to an image using php gd library. I have succeeded in generating the image and outputing it to the browser. What I want to know is... is there a way I could get the image to popup on the same page without loading and displaying the image in the php file that contains the code for creating and writing text to the image? Thanks in advance for your help.

My code:

```
<?php 

//Set content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Create image from existing image
$jpgImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('file.jpg');

// Allocate color for text
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpgImage, 255, 255, 255);

// Set Path to Font File
$font = 'arialbd.ttf';

// Text to print to image
$text = 'Testing text output';

// Print Text On Image
imagettftext($jpgImage, 75, 0, 50, 400, $white, $font, $text);



// Send Image to Browser
imagejpeg($jpgImage);

// Clear Memory
imagedestroy($jpgImage);

?>
```

Can Bootstrap 3 be used to accomplish this task? Thank you

Comment: If you use AJAX you can get JavaScript (jQuery for Bootstrap I believe?) to receive the newly created image URL and your AJAX "on complete" listener can create a popup and use the returned URL as the source. Use answer here as a starting point for Bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220462/how-to-show-a-url-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog-on-button-click

Comment: pass this script as src to image tag

Comment: No Big Chris, I dont use AJAX but I'll look through the link you sent. @charlietfl I tried that but it unfortunately didn't work

Comment: tried it how? If php outputs to browser should also work as src for `<img>`

Comment: by replacing `src` of `<img>` with the php file containing the imagecreate() code.

Comment: @charlietfl since the image is not saved to the server, I want it to be sent to the browser and the modal simultaneously, thereby not showing the image in the browser but it'll be sent straight to the modal. Thanks.

Comment: that's the whole point of putting it in an image tag pointed at your php script. Or could create image in browser using base64 data via ajax

Comment: @charlietfl I haven't learn ajax yet

Comment: I'll let you know if it succeeds