# bootstrap 3 - clear shared remote modal content between displaying?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a shared remote modal.  my problem is after closing the modal, on next open it shows the same content.

this is the same issue as here, but for bootstrap 3: [Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime)

how can i clear the modal between load/show's?

thanks.

Comment: What effort you had done? Pleas provide some code what you had done tried, so we can know your real issue

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18134067/1596547

Comment: @kolonelpeteruk Dude, that grammar...

Answer (score 3):

thanks bass!

in case anyone else lands here, this indeed works:
[Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime/18134067#18134067)