# Bootstrap 3.2.0 modal remote body content update

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

Does someone have a **working** example where multiple remote links have to be loaded into the modal?
What I want is a datatable and when one clicks on a link in the row, I want to open the edit page for that row.
e.g. edit.php?id=xyz.

My example works only for the first row I want to edit, when I click on a different row, the content of the first row is loaded.

I've been searching and this topic was the closest, however it does not work for bootstrap 3.2.0

[Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime/18134067#18134067)

Comment: The `remote` modal feature is being deprecated. You're better off implementing the loading functionality you need yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap [modal usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) says that the remote content **will be loaded one time**. So, what you have to do is remove the content of the modal when you close it. That will allow new content to be loaded.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal').find('.modal-content').empty();
});
```

Comment: I believe the `.find('.modal-content').empty()` might be unnecessary (although harmless), but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tested it with my code and it still does not work for bootstrap 3.2.0. But since it is being deprecated, I will need to create a new physical page for the pop up...

Comment: @user3253002 I'm using that code with Bootstrap 3.2.0, there is probably something in your code interfering with it.

Comment: @azeós can you tell me which version of jquery you use?

Comment: @user3253002 jQuery v1.11.1