# load bootstrap modal popup every request

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I'm using bootstrap modal popup(call those modals dynamically).

All are working fine but it does not show the updated content until I reload the page. This because hide and show events. I'm using the events like wise.

*this for show the modal*

```
 $('ModalID').modal({ remote: "RemoteURL"});
```

*this for hide the particular modal*

```
 $('ModalID').modal("hide");
```

If I have single modal it's OK but if I'm managing more then one modal at a page, it will not give the updated modal.

So is there is any possibility to reload the modal pop-up for each request instead of showing the modal which was already loaded, or any other way to show updated modal each and every time?

Comment: The `remote` option of modals is deprecated. I would advise against using it; just implement the loading yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similiar problem with Bootstrap and solved it by manually using JS api like this:

```
var ajaxModal = function(url,div,update_div){
  if(div===undefined){
    div="#myModal";
  }
  if(update_div===undefined){
    update_div="#myModalContent";
  }
  $.get(url, function(data){
    $(update_div).html(data);
    $(div).modal({});
  }).fail(function(){
    alert("błąd");
  });
};
```

Comment: this one works for me `$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});`