# Bootstrap Modal won't reset after opening once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The bootstrap modal window which appears on clicking "Add Column" won't reset once closed. As a result, I'm not able to add more than one value to the "Master table". The below code doesn't seem to work:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Can anyone help?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjmf8qqt/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to add more than one row because of repeating ID attributes. 
Inside the `#modalAdd` method you are appending a new row which has a td like this `<td id="colName">`. Because of this repeating ID attribute `$('#colName').val()` is not working any more.

About `removeData` I guess it works only for remote Data as pointed out here **[Twitter bootstrap remote modal shows same content everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime)**

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice the id at all.