# Disable javascript UJS caching (Rails 4)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ujs

I am using Rails 4 and unobstrusive javascript(UJS) to make a ajax call:

I'd like to disable the caching so that if somebody clicks the same link again and that the content in databse has changed, a new content will load inside the modal.

I want to use UJS and not vanilla javascript or metas.

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603455/1467802) do:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

How to write this with Rails?

```
<%= link_to "view", show_opportunities_path, remote: true, cache: false %> does not work.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: could you be more explicit/ give more details because I don't use anywhere http-equiv="Cache-Control". I'mm asking a question very specific to Rails.

Comment: and I don't want to disable caching on all browser, nor on all my reqetss, just on ONE specific modal

Comment: if unobtrusive javascript uses jQuery ajax then what `some people do` will work fine

Comment: @charlietfl true if it enables me disable caching on one specific MODAL and not all files/pages/modals