# Jade open bootstrap modal popup on anchor tag click

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug, mean-stack

I'm creating an app using MEAN stack and my Express view template engine is jade.

I have a list of JSON objects coming from API. I'm displaying a few fields in a table of rows. There is a hyperlink in the table for each row. Upon clicking this hyperlink, a modal popup should appear displaying a few other fields from the JSON returned by API.

I have managed to do this part but all the hyperlinks are displaying data for the first object.

Here is my Jade code where I'm iterating over the list of JSON objects and building hyperlinks.

```
a(href='#', data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal') #{incident.incidentNum}
          #myModal.modal.fade(role='dialog')
            .modal-dialog.modal-lg
              .modal-content
                .modal-header
                  button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') &times;
                  h4.modal-title #{incident.incidentPriority} - #{incident.incidentNum} - #{incident.applicationName}
                .modal-body
                  form.form-horizontal
                    .form-group
                      .row
                        label.pull-left.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1.control-label Description
                        label.normal-font-weight.pull-left #{incident.description}
                      .row
                        label.pull-left.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1.control-label Impact
                        label.normal-font-weight.pull-left #{incident.impact}
                      .row
                        label.pull-left.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1.control-label Started On
                        label.normal-font-weight.pull-left #{incident.dtStarted}
                      .row
                        label.pull-left.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1.control-label Contact
                        label.normal-font-weight.pull-left #{incident.contact}
                .modal-footer
                  button.btn.btn-default(data-dismiss='modal') Edit
                  button.btn.btn-default(data-dismiss='modal') Email
                  button.btn.btn-default(data-dismiss='modal') Close
```

I believe all modal windows are displaying only first data objects cause of the

```
data-target='#myModal'
```

The id is same for all modals.

How to display each JSON object data in its own modal window when the anchor tag is clicked?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287169/566434 seems to help.