# jQuery: Result of script gets deleted after execution - removeData() running on the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a modal window used to update or add a new object `Store`.

This modal has a cascading dropdownlist for two properties: `Department` and `District`.

**How should it work:**

We first identify if we are in the situation of creating or updating a `Store`.

In case is a **new** `Store` the modal opens and using jQuery we present a default value for the `District` dropdownlists (since no `Department` has been chosen yet).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var wasclicked = 0;
        var $this = this;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
                //is AddNew Store button is hitted, this var = 1
                wasclicked = 1;
            };

            $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                //global.wasclicked = 0;
                wasclicked = 0;
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });

            $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                console.log($('#DistrictID').length);
                //if wasclicked equals 1 that means we are in the AddNew Store scenario.
                if (wasclicked == 1) {
                    //a default value is sent to District dropdownlist
                    var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                };


            });
        });

</script>
```

However, at this moment, after the default value is added, after a fraction of a second, the value gets deleted.

[image]

[image]

**What I've tried**

I've noticed that when I remove this line of code:

```
$(this).removeData('bs.modal');
```

From the previous script, it works ok, but I need that code in order to clear the data from the modal if I need to use the modal to edit another `Store`.

Plus, when I debug the project the debugger did not stop at the breakpoint of that line, so I'm not sure why it's somehow executing in the background? Is it because it's wrapped inside the function `document.ready()`?

I've been struggling with this for days. I thank for any helpful comment.

**Aditional info:**

**Online version of the project:**

There is an online version for this for debugging:

http://plataformafantasypark.azurewebsites.net/

user: adelgado password: $Adelgado33

Under the menu 'Tiendas' -> 'Registro'

**Button that calls the modal:**

```
<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" 
         data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  NEW STORE
        </a>
</div>
```

**The Modal:**

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models

<form asp-action="Create" role="form">    
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
    { Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo: Tiendas") })

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            {... more elements}
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is #modal-action-store ? Is it a button or just a normal div/container?

Comment: Is it a button. I'll edit the question to add the code at the end.

Comment: If possible, try to give your question a working snippet example (by including libraries and so on in the snippet).

Comment: This might seem a bit random, but $(...).on('hidden...') is not really valid. It makes me scratch my head, and wonder if you're not trying to do something more like this -> https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: @James I don't know if I would be able to replicate the error thru snippet example, but I've updated the question to add a web address, user and password to access the project. Hope it helps

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin uhm, what I tried to achieve was that everytime the modal closes, the value of that variable is set to zero and clear the data from the modal if I use the modal, let's say, edit a `Store`. I'll have a look to the link provided

Comment: You're using a "remote" modal - ie its html is loaded from `/Stores/Create`.  I believe this html is loaded asynchronously using jQuery's $.get function.  What I suspect is happening is the ajax call is not returning with the content of that modal until after you have set the new `<option>`, so it overwrites your new option and kills it.  What you might want to try is get rid of the href attribute, load the modal's html yourself in show.bs.modal, and then in the $.get success function inject your extra `<option>`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be the best way to test what you are saying but: https://i.imgur.com/7tFcA4m.png in that photo, before the variable `items`'s value is defined and passed to `DistrictID` there are other fields in the modal form whose values have loaded (--Seleccione Cadena/MarcaComercial--).

Comment: I'd like to try what you are saying but my knowledge on jquery is limited :( could you give me an example as an answer?

Comment: @James for what I understand, your recomendation is to load the modal using something like @Url.Content("~/")' + "Stores/Create" ?

Comment: Can't you just add the missing <option> in the code that generates /Stores/Create ?

Comment: The thing is that this modal is used for both Create and Update, if I hardcode that <option> it would show when the modal is opened to update too and that is not required.

Comment: It catch my eye that this stops happening when I remove `$(this).removeData('bs.modal');` although the breakpoint don't activate at the time the <option> gets deleted, its so weird ):

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like(?):

```
$("#modalbutton").on('click', function () {
       //is AddNew Store button is hitted, this var = 1

       wasclicked = 1;
 });
```

Comment: I've tried with `$("#modalbutton").on('click', function () { wasclicked = 1; });` (It can be review it on the online version I posted on the question). What would be the difference with this answer?

Comment: Oh, yeah. My bad. But you have to somehow watch for the click, and update the "var" with each click. The jQuery ".on" does not support what you gave it. Read the documentation -> http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to take manual control of the loading and inserting of the remote content received from /Stores/Create.  I'm not set up to test this but give it a try.

You will need to get rid of/comment out the existing `.on('showN.bs.modal')` handler, and you might have to get rid of the href on the `<a>` tag that invokes the modal, not sure.

```
$('#modal-action-store').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (wasclicked == 1) {
        // load the form, once it's done loading modify it as needed
        $('#modal-action-store').find('.modal-content').load('/Stores/Create', function () {
            $('#DistrictID').html('<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>');
        });
    }
});
```